# Git Hangs Running Any Command on Windows 10

Tags: windows, git

I've taken on a new client. Client wants their work done on one of their machines. They've installed Git on the host. When I run a Git command, Git hangs.

[image]

This happens regardless of the command I run, and it happens whether I run Git from Windows Powershell or DOS. Any ideas why Git hangs?

The machine is running the following specs:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8665U CPU @ 1.90GHz, 2112 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 32.0 GB
```

Windows PowerShell specs...

```
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.858
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.858
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

DOS specs...

```
Version 10.0.17134.1610
```

They've installed the following version of Git for Windows on the machine:

```
Version  2.28.0.windows.1
```

Comment: Some sort of antivirus or monitoring software that interferes with how things run on the system?  I'd try completely removing any third-party antivirus, management, and monitoring software and restarting the computer.  Also try Git Bash and see if that works.  Otherwise, ask your system administrator for help.

Comment: Client's desktop aupport is in the loop. Unfortunately removing the AV software isn't an option. Disable for a sec to test might be.

Comment: This works fine pretty much everywhere else, so it's likely some software on your system is the problem.  Unfortunately, there's a lot of potential culprits on Windows systems, so it's hard to guess which program is the bad actor.

Comment: Tell me about it. Time to break out the sage and holy water.

Comment: The answer is.... security/anti-virus software. This issue happened on a client's laptop. They had just pushed a new security/anti-virus product to the machine, which caused the issue. They wouldn't tell me the name of the product, and for privacy reasons, I'm not going to dig. @bk2204 if you add your comment as an answer, I'll tag it as "the answer". Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to some sort of antivirus or security software on the machine.  Unfortunately, these tools can inject code into various processes and cause problems, especially programs which are compiled in a nontraditional way.  Many of these program also cause problems with sandboxing techniques like those used in Chrome and therefore actually worsen the security of the system.

My recommendation for any Windows user who is potentially having a problem like this is to completely uninstall that software and reboot.  Disabling it is often not enough.  Windows Defender is much less likely to cause problems as far as antivirus software and additionally works better with various features such as WSL.